# compile all over again if I missed an option?

Tags: qt, compilation, dependencies, static-libraries

To link statically(Qt application),

I compile qt library with -static option but without -static-libgcc option.

It was my mistake.

do I have to reconfigure and recompile whole library again?

or is there some solution for this?

Comment: pls post your *.pro file and what's your problem? pls describe it more precisely. Error messages so on...

Comment: Yes, you do if You want to get complete static library.

Comment: since I missed -static-libgcc option, the application still has dependencies. such as libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll libstdc++-6.dll libwinpthread-1.dll. to remove this dependencies, I need should've configure with static-libgcc option and compile but I missed. I wonder if I have to 2hours long compile again

Comment: You need a better machine to run your compilations on. A static compilation of your application, with link-time optimizations, will effectively generate the code for every part of the Qt library that you're using in your application. If it takes 2 hours to compile Qt, then it might take several minutes to *link* your application, each and every time you build it, even if you only changed a single file. You'll also need plenty of memory, and you must use a 64 bit system. Linking will fail on 32 bit systems. I find that to be productive with static builds, a Qt build needs to take ~15min.

Comment: It's not about building my application. It's qt library. qt library is big. and it takes 2hours to compile. My application is small and it takes several seconds to compile and linking.